# Extending an existing matrix in scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a N*N matrix:

```
N=3
x = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix( (N,N) )
for _ in xrange(N):
    x[random.randint(0,N-1),random.randint(0,N-1)]=random.randint(1,100)
```

Assume the matrix looks as below:

```
    X       Y           Z
X   0       [2,3]       [1,4]
Y   [2,3]   0           0
Z   [1,4]   0           0
```

How do I add the N+1 vertex without disturbing the existing values?

```
    X       Y           Z       A
X   0       [2,3]       [1,4]       0
Y   [2,3]       0       0       0
Z   [1,4]       0       0       [1]
```

Would the entire matrix need to be re-constructed?
When I try vstack to add a new row,I get an error:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse as sp
>>> c=sp.coo_matrix(x)
>>> c.todense()
matrix([[  1.,   3.,   5.],
        [  2.,   6.,   4.],
        [  8.,   2.,  10.]])
>>> sp.vstack([c,sp.coo_matrix(1,3)])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    sp.vstack([c,sp.coo_matrix(1,3)])
  File "c:\working\QZPkgs\eggs\scipy-0.10.1-py2.6-win32.egg\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 293, in vstack
    return bmat([ [b] for b in blocks ], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "c:\working\QZPkgs\eggs\scipy-0.10.1-py2.6-win32.egg\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 355, in bmat
    raise ValueError('blocks[:,%d] has incompatible column dimensions' % j)
ValueError: blocks[:,0] has incompatible column dimensions
```

Comment: Your edit only doesn't work because of incorrect syntax - use `sp.vstack([c, sp.coo_matrix((1,3))])`. Note the argument to create a matrix is always a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on what you are expecting the matrix to look like after you add to it. If you want to add a row to the matrix, use `sparse.vstack`:

```
from scipy import sparse
from numpy import random
N=3
x = sparse.lil_matrix( (N,N) )
for _ in xrange(N):
    x[random.randint(0,N-1),random.randint(0,N-1)]=random.randint(1,100)

x = sparse.vstack([x, sparse.lil_matrix((1,3))])
```

If you wanted to a degree of freedom to a linear system, so that the resulting matrix would be square, use `sparse.bmat` instead of `sparse.vstack`:

```
x = sparse.bmat([ [x, None], [None,sparse.lil_matrix((1,1))] ])
```

In the first example, x is expanded from 3x3 to 4x3, while in the second example x is expanded to 4x4.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not assigning the output of the `todense()`.

Try:

```
c_dense = c.todense()
sp.vstack([c_dense,sp.coo_matrix(1,3)])
```